# Xamarin Not working Debug (Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Created Android App.
Choose your device (Galaxy s4) and clicked Debug. Everything worked.
Then, change the file `MainActivity.cs`

Replace this:

```
button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count ++);
```

To this:

```
button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks two!", count ++);
```

I restart Debug, but the changes are not displayed and so every time.

If you check "Embed assemblies in native code" everything works, but at compile time becomes longer.

What could be the problem?

Xamarin Studio 5.9.3
Test on android 4.4.2 and 4.1.2

P.S.
If the "clear data" in the application, or "Upload to Device" in Xamarin Studio, then it works.

Answer (score 3):

I presume it is the *[Fast deployment](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Fast_Deployment)* option which causes you issues here:

> Fast deployment works in concert with the shared runtime to further
>   shrink the Android application package size. [...] Fast deployment is
>   known to fail on devices which block adb from synchronizing to the
>   directory /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.**override**.

Try turning it off in the properties of your Android project.

Comment: As far as I know Fast Deployment can use a different path.

For example this: `/ storage / sdcard0 / Android / data / @ @ PACKAGE_NAME / files / ....`

But for some reason, this folder is empty. To write to the access rights are not necessary.